# Help me to intergrate product database to Wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database

I am converting my company's website from ASP.NET to Wordpress. Everything is fine except that the old database of the website is designed to be quite troublesome for the conversion process.

I need to transfer the database of the company's products. I now have 3 tables as follows:

- Table 1: Product details: includes fields for product ID, product name, price, image ....
- Table 2: Product author reference: includes 2 fields: Product ID and Author ID.
- Table 3: Author details: including author ID fields, author names, addresses, images ...

I want to transfer this database to Wordpress and manage my products with Woocommerce, you can guide or give some suggestions to combine the 3 tables into a complete database to help me is not.

I sincerely thank :)

Comment: This sounds beyond the scope of what can be answered here. You need someone who knows both the WordPress database as well as your previous database, and who has knowledge on importing data to WordPress. Essentially, you need a custom importer that can call the proper WordPress methods to insert posts, attachments, postmeta, etc... That sounds like a much larger undertaking than what can be handled here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem and want to share it with anyone who has problems like me.

First, you should find out about a few simple SQL commands to make it easier to manipulate the database. I learned them at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

My idea is that I will export all the data I need into a single .csv file. In order to do this you will need to work right in the SQL Server command line with commands like INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN ... and save all the data you already have on a table and export it to a .csv file only.

After you have created the .csv file with the desired data, you will compare what you need to add to Wordpress, in my case, I will create 1 custom taxonomy for Product Type to manage the author. of books. I also use the Advandced Custom Field plugin to create some additional fields needed for my product data.

Finally I use WP All Import plugin of Soflyy to import all my data into Woocommerce.
That's all I did to switch my database, I know it may be very lengthy and not quick, but I still want to share it to help people.

Thank you for reading my article. :)